# Apache Pig 0.8.1 double NaN

Tags: hadoop, double, apache-pig, nan

I have a custom pig storage input mechanism that is placing a bunch of summary statistics values (like skewness, kurtosis, medians, etc..) into tuples. Specifically, these numbers are assumed to be doubles so doubles are being placed in the tuples.

The problem is, when the skewness/kurtosis are NaN in the java side, they seem to map to NaN in Pig and I can't figure out how to work with them even though I've defined the tuple schema to work with them as the "double" datatype.

NaN seems to sort higher than the highest double, so doing an order by in descending order seems to place all of the NaN's first. I've tried doing a filter by "skewness is not null" but that doesn't work.

Documentation and google aren't telling me much about how to work with these values. I need to be able to work with these numbers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

NaN is short for "Not a Number". "work with these numbers" embodies a basic misconception of thinking of them as numbers. They are not meaningfully comparable to numbers, so there is no right sort order for them.

You should be filtering them out, or finding out where they came from and fixing that. The sort of thing that can lead to a NaN is calculating the arithmetic mean of an empty set by dividing the total value by the number of elements.

If you do not have a direct "isNaN" test available, you can detect them by the special property that a NaN is not equal to anything, not even itself.